# Tailwind CSS classes do not work in Visual Studio 2022 (not Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c#, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, visual-studio-2022

As mentioned in the title, I'm trying to get tailwindcss to work in Visual Studio 2022 because I want to use React + C# to build a website. However, nothing seems to work when I try to use tailwind CSS classes.

Here is my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./ClientApp/src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts}'],
    mode: "jit",
    //important:true,
    theme: {
        screens: {
            sm: '450px',
            md: '768px',
            lg: '976px',
            xl: '1440px',
        },
        colors: {
            'blue': '#1fb6ff',
            'purple': '#7e5bef',
            'pink': '#ff49db',
            'orange': '#ff7849',
            'green': '#13ce66',
            'yellow': '#ffc82c',
            'gray-dark': '#273444',
            'gray': '#8492a6',
            'gray-light': '#d3dce6',
        },
        extend: {
            colors: {
                primary: "#ffffff",
                secondary: "#aaa6c3",
                tertiary: "#151030",
                "black-100": "#100d25",
                "black-200": "#090325",
                "white-100": "#f3f3f3",
            },
            boxShadow: {
                card: "0px 35px 120px -15px #211e35",
            },
            screens: {
                xs: "450px",
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

My `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
        tailwindcss: { config: './tailwindcss-config.js' },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

My CSS file:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    color-scheme: dark;
}

.nav-title {
    padding-left: 0.75rem;
}

.hash-span {
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    display: block;
}

.black-gradient {
    background: #000000; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to right, #434343, #000000 ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient( to right, #434343, #000000 ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.violet-gradient {
    background: #804dee;
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #804dee 0%, rgba(60, 51, 80, 0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, #804dee 0%, rgba(60, 51, 80, 0) 100% );
}

.green-pink-gradient {
    background: "#00cea8";
    background: linear-gradient(90.13deg, #00cea8 1.9%, #bf61ff 97.5%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90.13deg, #00cea8 1.9%, #bf61ff 97.5%);
}

.orange-text-gradient {
    background: #f12711; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to top, #f12711, #f5af19 ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient( to top, #f12711, #f5af19 ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.green-text-gradient {
    background: #11998e; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to top, #11998e, #38ef7d ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient( to top, #11998e, #38ef7d ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.blue-text-gradient {
    /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333); */
    background: #56ccf2; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to top, #2f80ed, #56ccf2 ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient( to top, #2f80ed, #56ccf2 ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.pink-text-gradient {
    background: #ec008c; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to top, #ec008c, #fc6767 ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient( to top, #ec008c, #fc6767 ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.card-off-set {
    transform: translateZ(60);
}

/* canvas- styles */
.canvas-loader {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    animation: mulShdSpin 1.1s infinite ease;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes mulShdSpin {
    0%, 100% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em #ffffff, 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }

    12.5% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }

    25% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 2.5em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    37.5% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em #ffffff, 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    50% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0em 2.5em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    62.5% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    75% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -2.6em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    87.5% {
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff;
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio 2022, I also used Tailwind CSS 2022 Editor Support.
This is the `tailwind.extension.json`:

```
{
    "ConfigurationFile": "tailwind.config.js",
    "InputCssFile": null,
    "OutputCssFile": null
}
```

The component that uses the tailwind classes

```
const NavMenu = () => {
    return (
        <div className="w-full border-2 border-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 bg-primary">
            <h1 className='px-5 py-5' >Title</h1>

        </div>
    )
}

export default NavMenu;
```

Lastly, this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, even with the class name there is no padding. I tried many different things like bg-primary, p-[300px], etc nothing works at all.

Do anyone know if Visual Studio 2022 actually supports tailwindcss or should I try something else?

Comment: Maybe have a look at: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheronWang.TailwindCSSIntellisense